# Deploying docker container of Kibana 4 with port-mapping on Mesos/Marathon

Tags: docker, mesos, mesosphere, marathon, kibana-4

I'm using mesos and marathon to deploy a container of Kibana 4. The JSON to deploy is:

```
{
    "id": "/org/products/kibana/webapp",
    "instances": 1,
    "cpus": 1,
    "mem": 768,
    "uris": [],
    "constraints": [
        ["hostname", "UNIQUE"]
    ],
    "upgradeStrategy": {
        "minimumHealthCapacity": 0.5
    },
    "healthChecks": [
        {
            "protocol": "HTTP",
            "path": "/",
            "portIndex": 0,
            "initialDelaySeconds": 600,
            "gracePeriodSeconds": 10,
            "intervalSeconds": 30,
            "timeoutSeconds": 120,
            "maxConsecutiveFailures": 10
        }
    ],
    "env": {
        "ES_HOST":"172.23.10.23",
        "ES_PORT":"9200"
    },
    "container": {
        "type": "DOCKER",
        "docker": {
            "image": "myregistry.local.com:5000/org/kibana:4.0.0",
            "network": "BRIDGE",
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 5601,
                    "hostPort": 0,
                    "servicePort": 50061,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ]
        },
        "volumes": [
          {
            "containerPath": "/etc/localtime",
            "hostPath": "/etc/localtime",
            "mode": "RO"
          }
        ]
    }
}
```

But when I post it, the kibana app never wake up and the stderr log is:

```
I0227 12:22:44.666357  1149 exec.cpp:132] Version: 0.21.1
I0227 12:22:44.669059  1178 exec.cpp:206] Executor registered on slave 20150225-040104-1124079532-5050-952-S0

/kibana/src/index.js:58
      throw error;
            ^
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL
  at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
  at Server._listen2 (net.js:1024:19)
  at listen (net.js:1065:10)
  at net.js:1147:9
  at asyncCallback (dns.js:68:16)
  at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:121:9)
```

After that I try to eliminate a port mapping, because I found some references indicating that it's an port or network configuration problem. Then my Kibana 4 web app wake up fine, but I need configure a port-mapping to access via HTTP. I have not idea at about why marathon has problem with **network** and **portMappings** config. Some help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nasty problem, and I encountered it as well (running Kibana 4 on Mesos + Marathon).

**The short answer:**

If you use current master of the Kibana repository, this won't happen - the relevant code has changed in the 4.1.0 snapshot which is master at the time of writing.

**The long answer:**

4.0.0 has this chunk of code in `src/server/index.js`:

```
var port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || config.port || 3000;
var host = process.env.HOST || config.host || '127.0.0.1';
```

Marathon supplies `HOST` and `POST` environment variables by default, and the `HOST` variable is set to the Mesos slave's hostname. The above code makes Kibana try to bind to the IP address of the Mesos slave (which Marathon has placed in `HOST`), which will fail, as it's running inside a Docker container.

If you want to run 4.0.0, you can just patch these lines to:

```
var port = config.port || 3000;
var host = config.host || '127.0.0.1';
```

The code looks like this in master at the moment.